Getting the last row of an Excel file in the first 7 columns ignoring all formatting
I'm working on code that reads stuff from a Word file and extracts it to an Excel file. It needs to fill the file from the last line.
Problem is that only the first 7 columns are relevant, there is usually data in the 8th column. Could you help me figure out what code to write that checks for the last row in the first 7 columns?
It also has to ignore all formatting, only checking for text. I would stick to openxml, I would like to avoid using Excel interop.
Thanks in advance!
Robert
foreach (var row in sheetData.Elements<Row>().Reverse())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) // Only check the first 7 columns
    {
        var cell = row.Elements<Cell>().ElementAtOrDefault(i);

        if (HasText(cell, workbookPart))
        {
            lastRowIndex = row.RowIndex.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(lastRowIndex);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (lastRowIndex != 0)
        break;
} 

private bool HasText(Cell cell, WorkbookPart workbookPart)
{
    if (cell == null) 
        return false;

    if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
    {
        int sharedStringIndex = int.Parse(cell.CellValue.InnerText);
        SharedStringItem item = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(sharedStringIndex);
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.InnerText);
    }

    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.CellValue?.InnerText);
}

This is what I got but not only does it not ignore formatting for some reason, it also checks every column in the worksheet

I would highly recommend checking out the ClosedXml nuget package as it has built in methods for these kind of use cases. It greatly simplifies things!

Method 1 (M1)
Sub method1_preferred():
        ReDim res(1 To 8)
        For i = 1 To 8
            c_ = ActiveCell.Column + (i - 1)
            lr = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
            For r_ = lr To 1 Step -1
                If Len(ActiveSheet.Cells(r_, c_).Value) > 0 Then
                    res(i) = r_
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If res(i) = 0 Then res(i) = 0 'in case col empty - remove as req.'
        Next 
        MsgBox "row counts: " & Join(res, ", ")
    End Sub



M2
Sub method2_sloppy()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    nm = ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
        "=TEXTJOIN("","",1,BYCOL(" & nm & "!C:C[7],LAMBDA(a_,MAX(FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a_)),--(a_<>""""))))))"
    res = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveSheet.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("rel vals: " & CStr(res))
    
End Sub

Your activecell when running this must be the 1st column of 8 consecutive cols of interest.
Requires Office 365 compatible version of Excel.
The reason for not using evaluate directly with this function is because it doesn't work well with non-legacy / dynamic functions as far as I'm aware.

bonus
This is true too for any lambda functions you create a name for e.g.
=LAMBDA(rng_,BYCOL(rng_,LAMBDA(a_,MAX(FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a_)),--(a_<>""))))))

If you gave this the name "get_row_count" how? then you could simply evaluate any 8 consecutive cols (e.g. a:g) in excel, i.e.  get_row_count(a:g) works nicely in Excel but in VB, Evaluate("=get_row_count(C:C[6])") returns Error 2015.

̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿’̿’\̵͇̿̿\З= ( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀) =Ε/̵͇̿̿/’̿’̿ ̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿

